# Error after closing connection in WebSocket++

Tags: c++, boost-asio, websocket++

I've got this:

```
[info] asio async_read_at_least error: system:10058 (A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket had already been shut down in that direction with a previous shutdown call)
[error] handle_read_frame error: websocketpp.transport:2 (Underlying Transport Error)
```

after closing connection by **server** (not by browser client) in WebSocket++ lib. The server still works, but how can I fix this error?

**SERVER CODE:** http://pastebin.com/acbrjLvF

Comment: Could you tell what example code you took basis on ? Why don't you use  `set_close_handler` ? Please try to provide a more complete example.

Comment: @coincoin Yes, I did. The example: https://www.zaphoyd.com/websocketpp/manual/common-patterns/storing-connection-specificsession-information

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25260852/shut-down-websocket-connection?rq=1 -> does this help?

Comment: @Samer Tufail This is **server**, not client.

Comment: I mean no, this doesnt help.

Comment: @SzymonMarczak Please provide more code... Give your `print_server` class. What is different from the example ? How do you manage `on_close` method ? I think you are over complicating things... You should not have to call `close()` if you have used `set_close_handler` properly.

Comment: @coincoin Here you go: http://pastebin.com/acbrjLvF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by adding `m_server.pause_reading(handler)` before calling `m_server.close` on handler.